# MS Sql Server statement inside COUNT

Tags: sql, sql-server

It does work in BigQuery but i do not get what am I doing incorrectly in MS SQL Server;

```
CASE 
    WHEN COUNT( RSM.RECEIVED_AT BETWEEN DATEADD(day, -84,UDATE.SQLDate) AND UDATE.SQLDate ) >= 1 
    AND COUNT(SAL.DATE BETWEEN DATEADD(day, -7, UDATE.SQLDate) AND UDATE.SQLDate) >=2  
    AND COUNT(SAL.DATE BETWEEN DATEADD(day, -14, UDATE.SQLDate) AND DATEADD(day, -7, UDATE.SQLDate)) >= 2 
THEN 'True' 
ELSE 'False' END AS AVAILABLE
```

What is the issue??

- **Incorrect syntax near ')'.**

Comment: uhm...what's the rest of the query?, are you getting an error?, if so, what's the error message?

Comment: @Lamak have updated it, as well it highlighted the `) >= 1` this closing bracket

Comment: `COUNT( RSM.RECEIVED_AT BETWEEN DATEADD(DAY, -84,UDATE.SQLDate) AND UDATE.SQLDate ) > = 1`? Do you mean `COUNT( CASE WHEN RSM.RECEIVED_AT BETWEEN DATEADD(DAY, -84,UDATE.SQLDate) AND UDATE.SQLDate THEN 1 END) >=1`? You can't have a boolean expression within a `COUNT`, it requires a scalar expression.

Comment: @Larnu such a simple solution...... sorry and thank you

Comment: @Larnu - A boolean expression is still a scalar expression.

Comment: @MartinSmith I disagree. `Alias.Column = DATEADD(DAY, -1, GETDATE())` is a boolean expression, that has 2 scalar expression `Alias.Column` and `DATEADD(DAY, -1, GETDATE())`. You can't do things like `SELECT DATEADD(DAY, -1, GETDATE())` and expect the result "True"/"False". Nor could you have something like `COUNT({Boolean Expression})` as the OP has clearly displayed.

Comment: Scalar expression means returns a single value. Boolean expression does that. SQL Server doesn't implement SQL Boolean datatype so you are very limited in where you can use these values. In other systems you can indeed do `SELECT 1=1` and get a boolean result

Comment: Your example is like saying `SELECT DATEDIFF(DAY, '1900-01-01', GETDATE()) + DATEDIFF(DAY, '1900-01-01', GETDATE())` doesn't return a scalar result because it adds two components.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I *suspect* what you are after is:

```
CASE
            WHEN COUNT(CASE WHEN RSM.RECEIVED_AT BETWEEN DATEADD(DAY, -84, UDATE.SQLDate) AND UDATE.SQLDate THEN 1 END) >= 1
             AND COUNT(CASE WHEN SAL.[DATE] BETWEEN DATEADD(DAY, -7, UDATE.SQLDate) AND UDATE.SQLDate THEN 1 END) >= 2
             AND COUNT(CASE WHEN SAL.[DATE] BETWEEN DATEADD(DAY, -14, UDATE.SQLDate) AND DATEADD(DAY, -7, UDATE.SQLDate) THEN 1 END) >= 2 THEN 'True'
            ELSE 'False'
       END AS AVAILABLE;
```

As I said in the comments: "You can't have a boolean expression within a `COUNT` (or any other aggregate function), it requires a scalar expression. "